# download pdf from URL into gDrive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to download a PDF from a link in the following format

```
fileURL = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<...DOCID...>&revision=3970&exportFormat=pdf"
```

and add it to gDrive folder.

I have this code, but the generated file just contain "Blob" rather than the actual content

```
function dFile(fileName,fileURL) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
  var fileBlob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('..folderID..');
  var result = folder.createFile(fileName,fileBlob,MimeType.PDF);
  Logger.log("file created");
}
```

How to I download the actual PDF?

**Update:**

I have updated my code and now I get this as generated PDF. Which makes me think I need to auth, but not sure how to do it, I set up all auth in manifest already

```
function dFile(fileName,fileURL) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
  var fileBlob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('..folderID..');
  var result = folder.createFile(fileBlob).setName(fileName);
  Logger.log("file created");
}
```

[image: Generated PDF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
var fileBlob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
```

#### To:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
```

- I thought that in your endpoint, `getBlob()` returns the PDF format.
- In your script, `createFile` is used. By this, the required scope has already been included. But, if an error is related to Drive API, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

#### Note:

- In your endpoint, if `revision=3970` is not existing, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getOAuthToken()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken)

Comment: @Filippo Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.